# The precision of the long double output is not correct. What might be wrong?

Tags: c++, precision, math, long-double

I have a `long double` constant that I am setting either as const or not-const. It is longer (40 digits) than the precision of a `long double` on my test workstation (19 digits).

When I print it out, it no longer is displayed at 19 digits of precision, but at 16.

Here is the code I am testing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <cstdio>

int main ()
{
    const long double constLog2 = 0.6931471805599453094172321214581765680755;
    long double log2 = 0.6931471805599453094172321214581765680755;    

    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits10 + 1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "const via cout: " << std::setprecision(19) << constLog2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "non-const via cout: " << std::setprecision(19) << log2 << std::endl;
    std::fprintf(stdout, "const via printf: %.19Lf\n", constLog2);
    std::fprintf(stdout, "non-const via printf: %.19Lf\n", log2);

    return 0;
}
```

Compile:

```
$ g++ -Wall precisionTest.cpp
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out
19
const via cout: 0.6931471805599452862
non-const via cout: 0.6931471805599452862
const via printf: 0.6931471805599452862
non-const via printf: 0.6931471805599452862
```

I would expect `0.6931471805599453094` but instead get `0.6931471805599452862`.

Is there a reason that the 19 digits of precision are cut to 16 digits?

Here is my environment:

```
$ gcc --version
i686-apple-darwin9-g++-4.0.1 (GCC) 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5490)
```

I am seeing the same problem with other versions of gcc, e.g.:

```
$ gcc --version
g++ (GCC) 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-10)
```

I can look into NTL or other libraries but I'm curious what is causing this. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: If you really need this much precision, you should look into a separate library

Comment: That's fine, and I probably will, but I'd like to know why I'm getting 16 digits instead of the 19 that <limits> "promises".

Comment: Have you actually tried using a long double literal? like suffixing it with L ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I get this output:

```
19
const via cout: 0.6931471805599453094
non-const via cout: 0.6931471805599453094
const via printf: 0.6931471805599453094
non-const via printf: 0.6931471805599453094
```

But i'm using long double literals instead of double literals:

```
const long double constLog2 = 0.6931471805599453094172321214581765680755L;
long double log2 = 0.6931471805599453094172321214581765680755L;
```

Comment: With an `L` at the end of the literal, for those who didn't notice. ;)

Answer (score 4):

There are some subtle issues relating to hardware platforms and compile options that might be of interest:

- [https://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0954161793/networktheory-20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0954161793)
- [3.17.3 Intel 386 and AMD x86-64 Options (gcc-4.0.1)](https://web.archive.org/web/20090622125054/http://developer.apple.com/documentation//DeveloperTools/gcc-4.0.1/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html) (archived developer.apple.com documentation)
- [3.17.12 Intel 386 and AMD x86-64 Options (gcc-4.0.1)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.1/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html) (gcc.gnu.org documentation)

These `-m' options are defined for the i386 and x86-64 family of computers:

> -m96bit-long-double
>
> -m128bit-long-double
>
> These switches control the size of long double type.
>   The i386 application binary interface
>   specifies the size to be 96 bits, so
>   -m96bit-long-double is the default in 32 bit mode.  Modern architectures
>   (Pentium and newer) would prefer long
>   double to be aligned to an 8 or 16
>   byte boundary. In arrays or structures
>   conforming to the ABI, this would not
>   be possible. So specifying a
>   -m128bit-long-double will align long double to a 16 byte boundary by
>   padding the long double with an
>   additional 32 bit zero.
>
> In the x86-64 compiler,
>   -m128bit-long-double is the default choice as its ABI specifies that long
>   double is to be aligned on 16 byte
>   boundary.
>
> Notice that neither of these options
>   enable any extra precision over the
>   x87 standard of 80 bits for a long
>   double.
>
> Warning: if you override the default
>   value for your target ABI, the
>   structures and arrays containing long
>   double variables will change their
>   size as well as function calling
>   convention for function taking long
>   double will be modified. Hence they
>   will not be binary compatible with
>   arrays or structures in code compiled
>   without that switch.

Comment: In what situations adding 16 bits of padding to an 80-bit number help anything?  On a 32-bit bus, a halfword-aligned 80-bit number is going to span three words regardless of whether it starts on an even or odd halfword boundary.  On a 64-bit bus, it's going to span two bus-words regardless of the halfword on which starts.  On a 128-bit or larger bus, the probability of a randomly-placed item spanning bus-words will be the same for any alignment between 16 and 64 bits.  Is padding designed for non-x86 systems?