# Why are there type modifiers for constants?

Tags: c++, integer, literals, suffix

I can not understand what the purpose is of type modifiers for literal constants, like for numerical constants:

```
75 
75u     
75l  
75ul
75lu
```

In what cases could this possibly be useful? I mean if you already have declared a type modifier for the variable type, I do not see a need for this. If anybody could help me understand this, it would be amazing! Thanks!

Bonus question: Is "literal" the same as "constant" like could you just say "literal" instead of "literal constant"?

Comment: These are literal values , not variables

Comment: I know,I have not said that they were variables, right?

Comment: you said "type modifier for the variable type"

Comment: A little bit of reading: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal

Comment: Yea.. I said that because I do not understand if you already have declared the type modifier for the variable, like "unsigned int name", I do not see why you would need to set the numerical constant to have a type modifier of maybe unsigned too, so it would be "unsigned int name = 88u"

Comment: what if you were not assigning it to a variable?

Comment: It allows type agreement which is important for a number of reasons, including those given in answers, but striving for type agreement in any event is a good idea even when not strictly necessary (because ithe implicit conversion provided happens to be semantically correct).  If it becomes a habit, it reduces bugs in general because sometimes it will be necessary, but being a habit means you never need to think about when that is the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For integer literals, apart from what's in Bathsheba's answer, it's also used for various cases like suppressing warnings

```
unsigned int n = somevalue;
...
if (n > 5) dosomething();
```

Changing to `if (n > 5U)` and there'll be no more warnings.

Or when you do something like this

```
long long x = 1 << 50;
```

and realized that x is not what you expected, you need to change it to

```
long long x = 1LL << 50;
```

Another usage is for the `auto` keyword in C++11

```
auto a = 1;
auto b = 1U;
auto c = 1L;
auto d = 1UL;
```

The above will result in different types for the variable

For floating-point literals, using suffix will result in more correct result

```
long double a = 0.01234567890123456789;
long double a = 0.01234567890123456789L;
```

Those [may result in very very different values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21557816/995714). That's because a literal without suffix is a `double` literal value and will be rounded correctly to double, hence when `long double` has more precision than `double` it'll result in precision lost. The same will occur with `float`s due to [double-rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding) (first to double then to float, instead of directly round the literal to float)

```
if (0.67 == 0.67f)
   std::cout << "Equal";
else 
   std::cout << "Not Equal";
```

[The above will print out "Not Equal"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14103012/995714)

[What is the difference between casting to `float` and adding `f` as a suffix when initializing a `float`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33163772/995714)

Comment: @Lundin it'll generate a ["comparison between signed and unsigned" warning](http://stackoverflow.com/a/859979/995714). I don't get your latter point. `1 << 50` is an int expression which results in undefined behavior

Comment: You wrote "long double a = 0.01234567890123456789L;", so would you need the long suffix if the variable type already is long and you therefore can type any value that is valid for this type?

Comment: @sostack yes you always need the suffix, because otherwise it'll be rounded at double precision then upcast into long double as I said, and you'll lost digits at the end. see [The precision of the long double output is not correct. What might be wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/684112/995714), [Why do you need to append an L or F after a value assigned to a C++ constant?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1380653/995714), [Actual long double precision does not agree with std::numeric_limits](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2565512/995714)...

Answer (score 10):

Sometimes a literal *must* have a specific type. For example

```
void foo(const int&){
    // pay myself
}

void foo(const unsigned&){
    // reformat my disk
}
```

Then `foo(75)` and `foo(75u)` would have very different outcomes.

In fact, it is *so* useful, that from C++11 it's possible to define your own literal types. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal

Comment: Yeah, also sometimes you're storing a literal value in a non-const variable. Type modifiers NEED to exist for that reason. Saying "but we have const already" is missing the point because it's ignoring the situations where the variable we're putting things in isn't const.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most common cases where I see this is in `75ul << 18`. The input to the shift needs to have enough bits to allow that shift. `75` might be 16 bits, making a shift over 18 bits Undefined Behavior (bad). `75ul` is at least 32 bits.