# Repeating float number randomly interrupted

Tags: c++, math, floating-point

In my code I have the following line:

```
monthInt = intRate / 12.0f;
```

Where `intRate` (yearly interest rate) is a float assigned by user input, in this case the user chose `4`, which turned into `4.0` repeating. However, `monthInt` (monthly interest rate) ends up getting `0.333333343`. Where is the 4 coming from?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    float intRate;
    float monthInt;
    cout << endl << "Please enter the annual interest rate as a percentage: ";
    cin >> intRate;
    monthInt = intRate / 12.0f;
    return 0;
}
```

I don't believe that any of the other lines of code are relevant to the problem as they don't interact with these variables yet.

Comment: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) is worth a read. Can't comment on your code because you didn't include it.

Comment: @RetiredNinja the code is lengthy so i didn't include it, but I'll update it with the relevant lines

Comment: That's why you don't want to include your whole program. You need to do some work to make it a [mcve] that only includes what is necessary to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @Antonio1113 *"the code is lengthy"* -- It shouldn't be. What more do you need than `#include <iostream> int main() { float intRate = 4.0f; float monthInt = intRate / 12.0f; std::cout << monthInt << "\n"; }` to demonstrate the issue? (Or even more simply, reduce the body of the main function to `std::cout << (4.0f / 12.0f) << "\n";`.)

Comment: @Antonio1113 --  [It takes 3 or 4 lines of code](https://godbolt.org/z/E47e8G5Po).

Comment: It looks like you are using floats, rather than doubles. Floats generally support 6 to 7 significant digits. The digit you are talking about is the eighth. Doesn't explain why a 4 there precisely, but suggests it is nothing to be surprised by.

Comment: @everyone you're all right, I just added the lines of code from my program

Comment: *"I don't believe that any of the other lines of code are relevant"* -- There is no need to guess, as there is an easy test to see if other lines of code are relevant. Simply copy the code from the question, compile it as-is, then run the result. If the code compiles and the output is `0.333333343` then you have included all relevant lines of code.

Comment: @Antonio1113 *I don't believe that any of the other lines of code are relevant to the problem as they don't interact with these variables yet.* -- Yet you see the code that JaMiT and myself gave you are *full*, programs, not snippets.  This is what you should have done.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sorry if it's not as concise as possible, it's for an assignment and this is the only syntax we've learned so far.

Comment: Recall that the computer works in base 2, so the repeat will be different. Then it is truncated due to physical space limit. Then converted to base 10 for display.

Comment: @Antonio1113 Bottom line -- floating point math is not school-book math.  You are working with a binary-computing machine, not a decimal machine.  That decimal fraction (and calculations) has to be converted to binary, and that is where precision is lost.

Comment: If you change `intRate` and `monthInt` from `float` to `double`, then you will get about two times the amount of significant digits before a precision loss occurs. Also, I suggest that you remove the `f` suffix in `12.0f` (even if it does not matter in this case, because the number `12.0f` can be represented exactly as a `float`, assuming that IEEE 754 is being used).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @AviBerger Yes, kind of. It was a little bit over my head but thank you for your explanations/solutions.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Okay, that makes sense. Why do you suggest that I remove the f? I only added it because I thought my teacher said to add an f every time we have float numbers.

Comment: @Antonio1113 With the `f` the number is a `float`, without the `f` it is a `double`.

Comment: @Antonio1113: `12.0` is a `double` (double-precision floating-point number), whereas `12.0f` is a `float` (single-precision). In this case, a `float` is able to represent the number exactly (assuming IEEE 754 is being used), so it doesn't matter whether you write `12.0` or `12.0f`, but it would matter if you wrote something like `1.333333333333333333`, as this number cannot be represented exactly and you would be losing more precision with `float`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Ohhhh okay thank you so much that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: The nearest number representable in the binary32 format to ⅓ is 0.3333333432674407958984375.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel in this case it actually matters, because `intRate / 12.0f` will be done in float precision while `intRate / 12.0` is done in double precision (provided that `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` is the default value 0). The result will be different

Comment: @Antonio1113 `4.0f/12.0f` is equal to `0.3333333432674407958984375` in float precision so when truncating to 9 decimal digits it becomes `0.333333343`. `float` has only ~7 digits of precision. [Print more digits of the result and you'll see](https://godbolt.org/z/8vejGKvYr)

Comment: @phuclv: Yes, you are correct that writing `intRate / 12.0` will give you the result in double precision. However, the result will be assigned to a `float` variable, so any precision gained by performing the division in double precision will be lost again in the assignment.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel but one is under [double-rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding) and the other is rounded only once, so [in many cases the final `float` result will be different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42994415/995714)